# Problems using broadway.js and raspi-camera over websocket

Tags: websocket, camera, stream, raspberry-pi3, h.264

What I wanna do is use the PI to control a small vehicle I build. I want to control this over a webinterface and also want to use the PI-camera to get a livestream when driving.

I am using nodejs on the PI with this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/raspivid-stream to get the stream from the PI-camera. Here is my nodejs-code:

```
var raspividStream = require('raspivid-stream');
var stream = raspividStream();

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  stream.on('data', (data) => {
    ws.send(data, { binary: true }, (error) => { if (error) console.error(error); 
  });
});
```

and here the index.html:

```
...htmlstuff...
<canvas id="stream"></canvas>
<script src="decoder.js"></script>
<script src="player.js"></script>
<script>
    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://raspberrypi:8443');
    var p = new Player();
    p.canvas = document.getElementById("stream"); // the canvas - p$
    connection.onopen = function () {
      connection.send('Ping'); // Send the message 'Ping' to $
    };

    connection.onerror = function (error) {
      console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
    };

    connection.onmessage = function (e) {
      console.log(e.data);
      p.decode(e);
    };
</script>
...htmlstuff...
```

So far I get this errors in the browser console:

```
wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'.
falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation
failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: CompileError: AsyncCompile: Wasm decoding failed: expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f @+0
CompileError: AsyncCompile: Wasm decoding failed: expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f @+0
 Uncaught (in promise) abort({}). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
```

Anybody got an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There’s a static file asset in the latest version of Broadway called `avc.wasm`. You need to get your server to deliver it with the correct MIME Content-type, `application/wasm` so the decoder can load it.

Or you can try an older version of broadway using asm.js rather than WebAssembly. It’s [here](https://github.com/mbebenita/Broadway/tree/2b350d08bb5aa5a763f1d15118eca96963a4ecba/Player).